# SQL With Query and Union clause

Tags: with-statement

Is it possible to have more than one WITH statement and a Union clause? I cannot put IP and PHYS together because it overcounts the membermonth. Even tried a case statement for IP versus PHYS and that did not work. Right now I have several different queries. 1 to write the first WITH to a table. 1 to write the second WITH to temp table and then 1 query that inserts the results of the second WITH to the first WITH table.

Example:

WITH PData as   (
SELECT DISTINCT
period, type, MAX(Period) OVER (PARTITION BY type) as MaxPeriod, MemberMonth as MemCnt
FROM
database
WHERE
lob = 'commercial'
AND segmentproduct IN ('Indiv ACA', 'Indiv Legacy', 'Large Group FI-NR', 'Small Grp ACA', 'Small Grp Legacy')
AND servicetype in ('IP')
AND paidthrough IN (SELECT MAX(paidthrough)
FROM database WITH (NOLOCK))
GROUP BY
period, type, MemberMonth

)
SELECT  period, type, MemCnt,
Case WHEN period = MaxPeriod
THEN 'Current Period'
ELSE 'Prior Period'
END AS [Prior Current]
FROM PData

Union

WITH PData2 as   (
SELECT DISTINCT
period, type, MAX(Period) OVER (PARTITION BY type) as MaxPeriod, MemberMonth as MemCnt
FROM
database
WHERE
lob = 'commercial'
AND segmentproduct IN ('Indiv ACA', 'Indiv Legacy', 'Large Group FI-NR', 'Small Grp ACA', 'Small Grp Legacy')
AND servicetype in ('Phys')
AND paidthrough IN (SELECT MAX(paidthrough)
FROM database WITH (NOLOCK))
GROUP BY
period, type, MemCnt

)
SELECT  period, type, MemCnt,
Case WHEN period = MaxPeriod
THEN 'Current Period'
ELSE 'Prior Period'
END AS [Prior Current]
FROM PData2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with` *once* for a query but you can introduce multiple CTEs

The structure you need is

```
   with 
      pdata  as ( <query> ), 
      pdata2 as ( <query> )
    
    select cols
    from pdata
    union
    select cols
    from pdata2;
```